# How can i add nested object inside my state dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects

i have a state like this

```
const [data,setData] = useState({
    city: "",
    address: "",
    zipCode: "",
    phoneNum: "",
    commission: [{ commissionFor: "Invocing", commissionPercentage: "40" }],
```

and i have a dynamic form which will appear if user click on ```Add`` button

```
  <Form onFinish={onFinish}>
          <Form.List name="commision">
            {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
              <>
                {fields.map((name, index) => (
                  <Row key={index}>
                    <Autocomplete
                      onChange={(e, value) =>
                        setData((data) => ({
                          ...data,
                          [`${dataName}${index + 1}`]: e.target.value,
                        }))
                      }
                    />
                    <FormControl>
                      <InputLabel>Percentage</InputLabel>
                      <OutlinedInput
                        value={data[`${dataValue}${index + 1}`] || ""}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          setData((data) => ({
                            ...data,
                            [`${dataValue}${index + 1}`]: e.target.value,
                          }))
                        }
                        startAdornment={
                          <InputAdornment position="start">
                            {insideIcon}
                          </InputAdornment>
                        }
                        label="Percentage"
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                  </Row>
                ))}
                <Form.Item>
```

i want when the user fill the information , my `commission` object change like this

```
    commission: [{ commissionFor: "Invocing", commissionPercentage: "40" },{ commissionFor: "This is new Input", commissionPercentage: "80" }],
```

how can i achieve this ? i will appreciate some help

Comment: Well you'd get the user's input data, construct an object and `push`. What have you tried to this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a function

put it on change on every input

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

Create this function

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  setData({
  ...data,
  commission: {...data.comission, [`${dataValue}${index + 1}`] : event.currentTarget.value} })
}
```

Comment: didn't work. this event handler will clear my ```commission``` and then it will add new property values. and it's not in a single object. ```commission: [{ commissionFor: "Invocing", commissionPercentage: "40" },{ commissionFor: "This is new Input", commissionPercentage: "80" }],``` i want achieve this. any other way  ? thank you for your help

Comment: you can try on handleChange function let comissions = data.comission
comissions.push(newItem)
setData(data)

if does not work try to clone


let newData = Object.assign({}, data)
newData.comissions.push(newItem)
setData(newData)